# Funny notation with #

Tags: vba, excel

what does this mean?

```
if CDbl(Trim(Range("M" & r).Text)) > 0# then...
```

what does the # do??
and what does cdbl do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

****Here is a Cheat Sheet for DataTypes ****

Variable End with:

```
$ : String
% : Integer (Int16)
& : Long (Int32)
! : Single
# : Double
@ : Decimal
```

Start with:

```
&H : Hex
&O : Octal
```

Comparison between VB and VB.Net ([reference](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/datatypes.html))

Visual Studio .Net added Literal Types ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters))

Value End with: (For more complete list, refer the the reference)

```
S : Short (Int16)
I : Integer (Int32)
L : Long (Int64)
F : Single
R : Double
D : Decimal
```

Convert to:

```
CBool(expression)
CByte(expression)
CCur(expression)
CDate(expression)
CDbl(expression)
CDec(expression)
CInt(expression)
CLng(expression)
CLngLng(expression) (Valid on 64-bit platforms only.)
CLngPtr(expression)
CSng(expression)
CStr(expression)
CVar(expression)
```

Comment: Does VBA have the `Decimal` type? Does it have literal `Date` also?

Comment: I accidentally used the VB.Net convert functions. I have changed it to VB6/VBA

Comment: According to the VBA help file, yes. It is type 'Date' and 'Decimal'

Answer (score 10):

`CDbl()` convert an expression to a Double:

> A data type that holds double-precision floating-point
>   numbers as 64-bit numbers in the range
>   -1.79769313486231E308 to -4.94065645841247E-324 for negative values; 4.94065645841247E-324 to
>   1.79769313486232E308 for positive values.

"#" is the "type-declaration character" for a Double.
Following a number with this symbol means that it will treat the number as a double instead of trying to guess what exact variable type to use (it would likely have treated the 0 as a integer without this)

Comment: A similar trick that is useful in some languages (SQL, for one) is to use `0.0` instead of just `0`. This will force it to treat the number as some form of decimal instead of an integer. Not sure if this trick is useful in VBA.

Comment: when you type `0.0` into the VBA editor it will actually rewrite it as `0#`

Answer (score 3):

Visual Basic uses the pound sign (# ) to indicate double-precision values. So `0#` enforces to treat this constant as of type double. `CDbl` converts expression to double type. * Double means double precision floating point.

Answer (score 2):

CDbl casts the contents to a double value.  The # indicates it's a numeric double value.  VB and VBA are sometimes quite forgiving when you're dealing with numbers, which can prove to be dangerous!