# VBScript integers followed by #

Tags: javascript, vbscript, integer

I've two dimensional array full of integers that I need to rewrite in Javascript from VBScript, and it looks like:

```
a(1, 1) = 0.03435435:
a(1, 2) = 0#:
```

What is the `0#`?

Comment: *Just* at the end? That's odd. If it were beginning and end it would be a date literal, but `0#:` doesn't ring any bells. Mind you, we're going back a LONG way... :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829128/funny-notation-with

Comment: @AnthonyDJ That's VBA. In VBScript only `&h0&` would work (and require the `&h` prefix). `0#` is just invalid syntax.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, that looks very odd, and syntactically incorrect. Other VB languages support suffixes for types, where # on a variable or literal means that [it's a double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx), but VBScript only has Variant variables, so it's a syntax error in VBScript.

All the lines ending with a colon is also suspect. While that's legal syntax (as the colon separates statements on a single line, and one can have empty statements), it has no effect at the end of lines when there's no statement following. I have a hunch that this code was ported to or written in VBScript by somebody who was not entirely familiar with it.

If this code is actually running somewhere and not erroring, is it possible that `On Error Resume Next` is on? If so, and the line is setting a value to 0, since the default value of variables is Empty (and thus converted to 0 when used in a math context), it may just be that the line has never worked, the error got ignored, and yet the program kept "working" anyway by pure coincidence. This is just some complete speculation on my part, though.

If you're trying to port over what the original code it doing exactly, and you can modify and run the original, it may be worthwhile to print out the contents of that array after it's initialized, just so you can confirm that it indeed has the values that it looks like it should. It may not be the same as the values the original author intended, though, if there are other problems with other values.