# How to improve primitive VBA code for DCF model?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, primitive

I'm new to VBA and I've been trying to create a program that allows me to take a starting cash amount, discount that amount by a certain discount rate, and also multiply the discount rate by n years to find a given discounted cash flow based upon a given number of years. Does anyone have any tips for how I could make this code more efficient? Also, what are some tips for using a loop to sum together different sums of cash, such as "(100/1.01) + (100/1.01^2) + (100/1.01^3)?" Thanks in advance!

```
Sub DCF()

Dim z As Double, CashFlow As Double, DiscRate As Double, Periods As Double

CashFlow = InputBox("Enter initial cash flow: ", "Cash Flow")
DiscRate = InputBox("Enter discount rate in decimal form: ", "Discount Rate")
Periods = InputBox("How many periods (in years) are there?", "Periods")

z = CashFlow / (1 + DiscRate) ^ Periods

MsgBox Format(z, "$0.00")

End Sub
```

Comment: Easier and Better with Formula? As you can change one variable at a time? Imagine you want to know the results of 1 to 5 years with fixed CashFlow and DiscRate? Or convert it into a UDF (User Defined Function) and use within the worksheet with 3 input ranges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have is fine and only requires a loop to create the discounted cash flow.  This should do what you want:

```
Sub DCF()

  Dim z As Double, CashFlow As Double, DiscRate As Double, Periods As Double: z = 0#

  CashFlow = InputBox("Enter initial cash flow: ", "Cash Flow")
  DiscRate = InputBox("Enter discount rate in decimal form: ", "Discount Rate")
  Periods = InputBox("How many periods (in years) are there?", "Periods")

  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 1 To Periods:
    z = z + CashFlow / (1# + DiscRate) ^ i
  Next

  MsgBox Format(z, "$0.00")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. As a last question, what is the "#" that's next to "1' and "0" in the code?

Comment: If just shows the number is a double - see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829128/funny-notation-with)